# segfault using threads in C++ class

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I'm writing a program in C++ to do an internal chat on linux. The code has a class attribute containing private structure, this structure is instantiated in shared memory so 
that the same program running  in several terminals, can access the same data and make the chat work. My problem is that the chat has to read and write at the same time, 
so you have to create one thread for reading and another for reading, but i don't know hot to use it well and I am having a problem when I enter the thread, the pointer
to the shared memory structure is reset so to speak, pointing to the address 0x0 and gives me segmentation fault.

This is NOT my program, but not to put so many lines of code I have summarized in an example the part I'm doing wrong, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Why do i get seg fault?

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class bar {
private:
  struct SharedMessage{ 
     int  number=21;
  };

  SharedMessage* sharedMessage_;

public:
  void foo(void) {
    std::cout << "hello from member function: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << sharedMessage_->number << std::endl;
  }
  void thread (void){
    sharedMessage_=new SharedMessage;
    std::thread t(&bar::foo, bar());
    t.join();
    std::cout << sharedMessage_->number << std::endl;
  }  
};

int main()
{
  bar Object;
  Object.thread();  
}
```

Comment: did you mean `this` in place of `bar()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is that:

```
std::thread t(&bar::foo, bar());
```

creates an anonymous `bar` object and passes a copy to the thread.  The pointer of its  `sharedMessage` is uninitialized, and therefore the segfault when you try to access the `sharedMessage` number.

If you want to pass the current object using its initialized pointer,  you could do:

```
std::thread t(&bar::foo, this);
```

If you want to pass another object, you could do it as well, but you have to initalize the sharedMessage, for example by giving your class a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the c++ reference on thread. It seems like you need to pass the bar instance as std::ref(bar).

I think that the solution should be the following:

```
  void thread (void){
    sharedMessage_=new SharedMessage;
    bar instance;
    std::thread t(&bar::foo, std::ref(instance));
    t.join();
    std::cout << sharedMessage_->number << std::endl;
  }
```

Comment: Good idea to avoid an anonymous object with the ref !  But I'm affraid that the pointer to the `sharedMessage` in `instance` will still be uninitialized and hence the segfault will still happen.